# Trouble getting jasmine working with angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm having trouble understanding how to set up Jasmine to work with Angular so I can do testing.  I'm following the instructions [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/unit-testing) under the heading titled "Testing a controller".  According to the documentation, you should have your app & controller, defined like you normally would (this is pasted from the documenation):

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('PasswordController', function PasswordController($scope) {
  //controller code goes here (removed for brevity)
});
```

and then you should have as your testing suite code, for example (pasted from the documentation as well).

```
describe('PasswordController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.grade', function() {
    it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
      $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
    });
  });
});
```

But I'm terribly confused about a few things.

1. The documentation explains that you need to use `angular-mocks` to load in the controller, but in their example, they don't declare `ngMocks` as an app dependency (see the first block of code I pasted above).
2. It says that you can use `angular.mock.inject` to inject the controller into the current context.  I loaded in the script http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-mocks.js and now there is an `angular.mock` on the global scope, but it does not have an `inject` method.  Furthermore, since the testing code runs outside of the controller, I don't understand how using the `ngMocks` dependency in the angular app helps with providing global methods for injecting controllers.  The whole thing doesn't make sense to me.
3. Same goes for `module`.  It says you can use it for the `beforeEach(module('app'));`, and that it's provide by `angular-mocks`, but angular.mock has no `module` method.

If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered that problem was that my script tag for `angular-mocks` was **before** my script tags for Jasmine when it really needs to go **after**.  In the typical spirit of Angular "documentation", this was mentioned nowhere.  After rearranging the script tags both `module` and `inject` were globally available methods.

So to answer my first question, you don't need to put `ngMock` in the dependencies.  This answers questions 2 and 3 since `module` and `inject` are both now globally available.

So the scripts need to be placed in this order.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/boot.js"></script>
<!--angluar mocks script MUST go after the other declarations otherwise it won't add the inject and module methods to the scope -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```